# SQL Server Query won't run

Tags: sql, sql-server, networking

I am connected to a remote SQL Server instance

These queries works fine:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Provider  
SELECT TOP 1 * FROM Provider
```

but these don't

```
SELECT * FROM Provider  
SELECT TOP 2 * FROM Provider
```

and return this error after a long delay:

> Msg 64, Level 20, State 0, Line 0
>   A transport-level error has occurred when receiving results from the
>   server. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 0 - The specified network name
>   is no longer available.)

What configuration should I be looking at that would allow a single row result but not a multiple row result?

Comment: This doesn't look like any query issue. This looks like a network, or server issue. How many rows are in the Provider table?

Comment: Try `SELECT TOP 2 * FROM Provider` by itself.

Comment: The remote server probably set the remote query timeout. A remote query timeout option specifies how long, in seconds, a remote operation can take before SQL Server times out. A select * from a table will try to get all records from that table, which probably takes to long in your case. And the remove server kills the connection. You could add a WHERE clause to only get the records you need, instead of getting the whole table.

Comment: @LukStorms, the `remote query timeout` option only applies to remote queries (e.g. linked servers).  It is the client, not SQL Server, that times out normal queries.

Comment: @DanGuzman So if it's actually the client software that decides whether to timeout or not, then he probably needs to check if his connection settings include some (default?) timeout setting. And change that.

Comment: @LukStorms, assuming a modern .NET version is used, the exception is not a SQL Server timeout but due to the SQL connection being severed.  The SQL Server error log might provide some clue.  There may be some security software like a database firewall that is breaking the connection for suspicious queries.

Comment: This has nothing to do with your question but never do a top 1 or top 2 query without an order by clause.

Comment: @HLGEM Never? To just get a few RANDOM records quickly, a TOP n query will be faster without the ORDER BY.

Comment: The key there is random. You can't guarantee to  repeat what results you get. If you are doing an ad hoc query to see one record in the table as an example, but not in a production environment in code used by an application.

Comment: This is not a SQL query issue. This is a network connection issue. ORDER BY has nothing to do with it - it is a simple table with 109 rows in it and it should be able to return all of them immediately. It works fine on my ISP's test machine via a VPN but not on mine connecting with the same details. I have executed those one line queries one at a time ad nauseum - the top two work every time, the bottom ones fail every time. The connection isn't a problem but the resultset is or at least can be. I see the problem in Management Studio and Visual Studio and via code.

Comment: It *might* be a VPN problem but my ISP support guy has connected successfully using his VPN and using my credentials so I have to assume my machine configuration has a problem somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

I found the following 
Hey mate, another thing to try i found the following and have included the URL for you. Considering the first bit of trouble shooting didn't work for you

**Symptoms**
The stack trace of the error resembles the following:

```
A transport-level error has occurred when receiving results from the server. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 0 - The specified network name is no longer available.)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParserStateObject.ReadSniError(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, UInt32 error)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParserStateObject.ReadSni(DbAsyncResult asyncResult, TdsParserStateObject stateObj)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParserStateObject.ReadPacket(Int32 bytesExpected)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParserStateObject.ReadBuffer()
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParserStateObject.ReadByte()
```

**Cause**
The error is being caused by a timeout exception for long running queries. In previous versions of Visual Studio .NET, the exception was properly represented as a exception with a timeout description.

**Resolution**
Set the commandtimeout property of the command object to an appropriate value. Use a value of zero to wait without an exception being thrown.

Taken from https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/555938

Comment: Wow - that was a quick response! Not running a web based service and the SQL server instance is on my ISPs box so I have no control. Plus their tech-support are connecting and running the queries with no problem. Wasn't sure whether the netsh suggestion was for my machine or the server - tried it on mine anyway and no difference.

Comment: @simon Hewitt - sorry to here that. Bit tricky to pin point with out knowing the full technical design. I have heard of people having similar issues in the past. As you stated its on your ISPs infrastructure  it pretty much just opens up a brand new can of worms. Possibly try running a very simple query to see if it persists it could be time out.